# how to change the design of iframe youtube play button

Tags: html, css, angular, iframe, youtube

how can i change the design of iframe youtube play button using css and angular4

### youtube.html

```html
<div>
  <iframe class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vqxvEUKiT1g?autoplay=0&showinfo=0&loop=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <button class="btn">Play</button>
</div>
```

### styles.css

```css
iframe.video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.ytp-large-play-button svg{
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

### youtube.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'youtube.html'
})

export class YoutubeComponent {}
```